# Input and retrieve info from CPtrArray MFC

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, pointers, mfc

I have a problem when trying to extract values from an array of pointers. 
First I put data in the array like this :

```
RHExportType* rhet = new RHExportType;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            CString* strTemp;

            strTemp = CRHExportTypeCollection::GetTypesAndDescription(i);   //retruns the first pointer to an CString array


            rhet->type = i;     

            _tcscpy(rhet->extension, *strTemp);
            ++strTemp;
            _tcscpy(rhet->description, *strTemp);

            pArr.Add(rhet)
        }
```

RHExportType is an structure that has two fields as char[50] type and an one as int type.
pArr is declared as an out parameter in the function, CPtrArray& pArr.

And then I am accessing the data :

```
int sizeArr = m_RHExpType.m_ExpTypeArr.GetSize();
for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
{       
    RHExportType* pRHET = (RHExportType*)m_RHExpType.m_ExpTypeArr.GetAt(i);

    strTemp.Format(_T("%s (.%s)"), pRHET->description, pRHET->extension);
}
```

But no matter the value of the index(i) it always returns the last inserted value.
Am I adding the data wrong ? or the problem is at retrieving the data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are updating and inserting the same object to the array in each iteration of the loop. Hence, the object is getting the value of the last object.

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
{
    RHExportType* rhet = new RHExportType;
    ...
}
```

Comment: That was the problem, I was a little careless. Thanks.